# Calling customized C++ dll from Python

Tags: c++, python, windows, ctypes

My C++ IDE is Visual Studio 2012 Express Version, and my Python IDE is Aptana3 (64-bit). My computer is Windows 7 64-bits.

I've write a .dll with C++ (Win32 console application), which basically follows the instruction at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It works well when I call it with a C++ application.

Then I try to call it from Python by following codes:

```
import ctypes

d = ctypes.WinDLL("C:\\DynamicLibrary\\Debug\\MathFuncsDll.dll")
```

However, I've got following error:

```
File "`<pyshell#8>`", line 1, in <module>
d = ctypes.WinDLL("C:\\DynamicLibrary\\Debug\\MathFuncsDll.dll")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I've googled about this error message, and some posts say it because the compatibility between 32- and 64-bits. But I doubt it, since my IDE's and system are all 64-bit.

May I know what am I wrong?

Many thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Have you considered using IronPython?

Comment: @Inspector What of it? How do you link to native DLLs from IronPython?

Comment: `import clr; clr.AddReference(…)`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: If there is a bitness mismatch of native code, using `IronPython` would not solve the issue

Comment: @Inspector clr.AddReference is for managed DLLs. This one is native.

Answer (score 3):

The most common explanation for that error is that the system is attempting to load a 32 bit DLL into a 64 bit process, or vice versa. The fact that your system is 64 bit just makes that diagnosis more likely. Perhaps your Python is 64 bit, but the C++ project outputs a 32 bit DLL. Or vice versa.

In the question you state that your Python installation is 64 bits. In which case you need to look at your C++ project. What platform are you targetting? Win32 or x64? My money is on the answer to that question being that you target Win32.

That's the most likely explanation. Beyond that the next most likely cause is the exact same problem, but for one of the dependencies. The Python process and the DLL match, but when resolving the dependencies of the DLL the loader finds a DLL of the wrong bitness.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. Can you please amplify by adding how OP can determine the bitness of the dll and the Python Installation using `dumpbin \headers` and look for the entry for `machine`?

Comment: @Abhijit That's not how I would do it. The asker is compiling the DLL and so merely needs to check the target platform in the IDE. No need for reverse engineering.

Comment: May be, but when in doubt, I first check if there is a bitness mismatch. This is helpful, when using a third party dll. Any case, I have added my own answer

Comment: This may help: [64-bit C++ Development Under Visual Studio 2012 *Express*](http://www.kobashicomputing.com/64-bit-c-development-under-visual-studio-2012-express)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hi, David, Thanks for you answer. I am targetting to a Win 64 platform. My plan is to write a serie of C++ .dlls and call them from Python.

Comment: OK. My answer stands though.

Answer (score 0):

> I've googled about this error message, and some posts say it because
>   the compatibility between 32- and 64-bits. But I doubt it, since my
>   IDE's and system are all 64-bit.

Yes, your research is correct.

> My C++ IDE is Visual Studio 2012 Express Version, 
>   My computer is Windows 7 64-bits.

That doesn't guarantee that you would build a 64 bit binary. Infact, VS 2012 IDE is a 32 bit application. Its the compiler and the CRT which is responsible to generate a 64 bit binary.  And moreover the default settings for Visual Studio is to generate a 32 bit binary

You can easily google and determine how to build a 64 bit binary using Visual Studio. Alternatively, refer the link [How to: Configure Visual C++ Projects to Target 64-Bit Platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx)

> and my Python IDE is
>   Aptana3 (64-bit). My computer is Windows 7 64-bits.

That still doesn't say anything about your Bitness of your Python Installation .

When in doubt, check for the bitness of your `dll` and your `python.exe`. You can easily determine the bitness using `dumpbin`

```
C:\Python27>dumpbin /headers python.exe|grep "machine"
             14C machine (x86)
```

Comment: I've tried to change VS2012 to Win32 in Configuration Manager, however, still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Build your C code to X64 version

I tested it and actually works well